# SeleniumIDE doesn't find my Target

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

Allready tried "intro to css locators in selenium" and "css selectors for selenium"but they did not bring a solution. When using Selenium IDE 2.91 to record a webpage test, playing back the scenario ends in errors. IMHO the problem is a push button with aria-pressed that changes when hovering over it, pressed or unpres it. When doing those things the div class is changing from:

```
<div class="gwt-PushButton A gwt-PushButton-up" tabindex="0" role="button" style="" aria-pressed="false">
```

To

```
<div....gwt-PB-up-hovering tabindex="0" role="button" style="" aria-pressed="false">
```

And to

```
<div class="gwt-PushButton A gwt-PushButton-down-hovering" tabindex="0" role="button" style="" aria-pressed="true">
```

Rest of html code within the div is:

```
<input tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;" type="text">
<div class="html-face">Controle</div>
</div>
```

Record of selenium is 2 records:

```
1 click //div[5]/div[2]
2 click //div[5]/div[2]/div
```

> The info selenium gives = [info] Executing: |click | //div[5]/div[2] |
>   |  But because the button isnt really clickt on the next step goes in
>   error.

Any suggestions how to be able to make selenium click the button?
Already tried click using  `css=div.gwt-PushButton.GBKHVCADO2`

Comment: Through firefly i got a css path: html.force-scroll body.body div.GBKHVCADL- div.GBKHVCADI- div div.mainContent div.content div div.content div.GBKHVCADP2.content div.gwt-PushButton.GBKHVCADA3.gwt-PushButton-up div.html-face but using this also doesnt help. Button is not clickt